# Which will be the cheapest way to go to Leh from Jaipur?

Tags: budget, india

Which will be the cheapest way to go to Leh from Jaipur and how? It's my first time to go on such trip. I am so confused.

Comment: If you can get tickets, taking the train in 3rd class is likely to be one of the lowest price ways. Have you looked into that?

Comment: There's no train station anywhere near Leh, which is high up in the mountains in Jammu & Kashmir.

Answer (score 2):

Bus to [Manali](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Manali) via Keylong, two days (overnight in Keylong), Rs 700 or so on the public HRTC buses, around Rs 2000 on the plusher private ones.  Bus from Manali to Delhi, ~14 hours, Rs 500 up.  And finally train to [Jaipur](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Jaipur), 4+ hours, fares from Rs 150 or so (more on the expresses).

Alternatively, bypass the dangerous twisty mountain roads and fly to Delhi, then take the train.  Fares vary, but will be of the same order of magnitude as taking nice private buses, and far faster and more comfortable.

Comment: Is this reversed, or is there a typo or something? It says "to Jaipur" whereas the OP asks "from Jaipur".

Comment: Oops, it's indeed reversed, my brain read the title as "from Leh to Jaipur".  But the same instructions still apply, only in reverse ;)

Answer (score -2):

Booking a cab is a good option. There are many cab services available in Jaipur.

Comment: I doubt any cab service in Jaipur will agree to go to Leh. It is much better to hire a cab in Manali where the drivers atleast have the experience of driving to Leh. This looks like spam to me.

Comment: Have removed the recommendation.